# Font-weight changed on german letters

Tags: css, font-face

I'm trying to use androids roboto font on a website it works fine until I get a german letter in a text then it looks like the font-weight is changed.

Its imported like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'RobotoLight';
src: url('Roboto-Light-webfont.eot');
src: url('Roboto-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Roboto-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Roboto-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Roboto-Light-webfont.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

and then it looks like bellow.

[image]

Would this be of a faulty font or because of a css setting? Any suggestions of how this could be fixed?

Comment: Your font is not correct... I recommand you to [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts). They support characters like `ß ä ö ü`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: the font is faulty. If you want to use non-english characters and the Roboto-font dont download the web-prepared one. It seems to be reduced to be quicker to load and is there for missing some characters. Download the original and convert the fonts yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the font, but without more information (where did you get the font from, what did you do with it?), it is impossible to say what went wrong. But assuming you mean the [Roboto](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html) font distributed at developer.android.com (which is distinct from the Google font with the same name, by a different designer), just download their font package, unzip it, process it with Fontsquirrel [@font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator), and use the CSS provided by the generator. I just tested, and German characters appear OK.

The characters that look bolder might be from a normal (weight 400) typeface of the font, or from a different font, presumably because the light typeface does not contain them.